# Can i call multiple java script functions with in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I defined a JavaScript function using a custom service and I called this function using the service in my controller. This function uses two parameters: The first one is input which I am getting by hitting the below API and the second one is the value of the year which I'm getting using `ng-model` directive. When I am calling this function in my controller I am getting an error like `type is not defined` or `id is not defined` etc. Is it the right way to call a JavaScript function in the controller. Please suggest me.

```
$http.get("http://152.144.218.70:8080/USACrime/api/crimeMultiple?city="  +$scope.strCity + "&crime=" + $scope.type1 + "&model=" + model).success(function (result) {
    $scope.prograssing = false;
    console.log("manisha", $scope.strCity);
    console.log("kanika", result);
    $scope.output = result;
    console.log("monga", $scope.output);
    $scope.hex = hexafy.year_city($scope.output,$scope.type);
    console.log("service", $scope.hex);
});
```

**myapp.js**

```
var app= angular.module("myApp",["ngRoute","leaflet-directive","pb.ds.components"]);
var geomarker = new L.FeatureGroup();
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.year_city = function (input2,years) {
        if(years.toLowerCase()=="all"){
        years = "2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019";
    }
    var yrs = years.split(",");
    output = {};
    outerBoundary = {};
    boundary = {};
    boundary["boundaryId"] = input[0]["id"];
    boundary["boundaryType"] = input[0]["type"];
    boundary["boundaryRef"] = "C1";
    outerBoundary["boundary"] = boundary;
    output["boundaries"] =outerBoundary;
    themes = [];
    for(var i in input){
        crimeTheme = {};
        crimeThemeValue = {};
        crimeThemeValue["boundaryRef"] = "C1";
        result = [];
        for(var j in input[i]["prediction"]){
            dict = {};
            if(yrs.indexOf(input[i]["prediction"][j]["year"])>-1){
                dict["name"] = input[i]["prediction"][j]["year"]+" "+input[i]["crime"]+" Crime";
                dict["description"] = input[i]["crime"]+" Crime for "+input[i]["prediction"][j]["year"];
                dict["value"] = input[i]["prediction"][j]["count"];
                dict["accuracy"] = input[i]["accuracy"];
                result.push(dict);
            }
        }
        crime = input[i]["crime"].toLowerCase()+"CrimeTheme";
        crimeThemeValue["individualValueVariable"] = result;
        console.log('crimeThemeValue["individualValueVariable"]',crimeThemeValue["individualValueVariable"]);
        crimeTheme[crime] = crimeThemeValue;
        themes.push(crimeTheme);
        console.log("themes",JSON.stringify(themes));
    }
    output["themes"] = themes;
    console.log(output);
    return output;
    };
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated and it is not good to go with it. Instead you'd better use `.then(successCallback, errorCallback)`

2) To use a service method the proper way is to it like this:

```
app.service('myService', function() {
  var service = {
    method:method
  };

  return service;

  function method() {
   //Logic
  }

})
```

So in your case the way to go is:

```
app.service('hexafy', function () {
        return {
            years_city: function (input2, years) {

                if (years.toLowerCase() == "all") {
                    years = "2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019";
                }

                var yrs = years.split(",");
                output = {};
                outerBoundary = {};
                boundary = {};
                boundary["boundaryId"] = input[0]["id"];
                boundary["boundaryType"] = input[0]["type"];
                boundary["boundaryRef"] = "C1";
                outerBoundary["boundary"] = boundary;
                output["boundaries"] = outerBoundary;
                themes = [];
                for (var i in input) {
                    crimeTheme = {};
                    crimeThemeValue = {};
                    crimeThemeValue["boundaryRef"] = "C1";
                    result = [];
                    for (var j in input[i]["prediction"]) {
                        dict = {};
                        if (yrs.indexOf(input[i]["prediction"][j]["year"]) > -1) {
                            dict["name"] = input[i]["prediction"][j]["year"] + " " + input[i]["crime"] +
                                " Crime";
                            dict["description"] = input[i]["crime"] + " Crime for " + input[i]["prediction"]
                                [j]["year"];
                            dict["value"] = input[i]["prediction"][j]["count"];
                            dict["accuracy"] = input[i]["accuracy"];
                            result.push(dict);
                        }
                    }
                    crime = input[i]["crime"].toLowerCase() + "CrimeTheme";
                    crimeThemeValue["individualValueVariable"] = result;
                    console.log('crimeThemeValue["individualValueVariable"]', crimeThemeValue[
                        "individualValueVariable"]);
                    crimeTheme[crime] = crimeThemeValue;
                    themes.push(crimeTheme);
                    console.log("themes", JSON.stringify(themes));
                }
                output["themes"] = themes;
                console.log(output);
                return output;

            }
        }
    })
```